# Value of t statistic equal to infinity

Tags: multiple-regression, sas, linear

Does anyone know when PROC REG with `selection = stepwise` in SAS gives *t*-values equal to infinity?

I am getting an $R^2 = 1$. My data set has $n = 50$ observations and about $p = 20$ independent variables.

Comment: Could you provide code/output, to help us better understand what may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You have far too many independent variables.  This has caused your formula to be completely determined by overfitting.

The general rule of thumb for regression is that you want at most 1 variable for every 10 observations, so you would be able to look at a maximum of 5 independent variables.

Even this amount of overfitting doesn't usually give R^2 = 1, but you probably have some other oddity as well.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the rule of thumb? ESL discusses issues when $n < p$, but doesn't mention the 10:1 ratio.

Comment: I've heard it lots of places and I'm sure I've seen it somewhere, but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 1):

$R^2=1$ means that your dependent variable (say $Y$) is a linear combination of some of your independent variables (say $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$), that is:

$$Y = a_0+a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\ldots+a_kX_k$$

for some $a_0, \ldots a_k $.

(Notice lack of $\varepsilon$ - error term above).

Run simple linear regression (without stepwise selection procedure) to find which $X$'s determine your $Y$ and what $a$'s are.